# How do I start the 'contains' decision operator in ColdFusion at a specific character in a string?

Tags: coldfusion

My question is super simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.  I'm trying to find the character 'C' in a seemingly random 10 character string.  However, I only care about the character 'C' if it is the 6th character in the string.  If the character 'C' is found at the 6th position in the string the string should be enclosed in dashes (-).   For example:

14CSI14550 should not be enclosed in dashes, because the C is the 3rd character in the string.
14EFEC4933 should be enclosed in dashes, because C is the 6th character in the string.
14CSIC5005 should also be enclosed in dashes even though there is another C in the string.

Here is what I have so far, I think I'm on the right track with contains, but I think I need it to start looking for C at the 5th character in the string, so as to skip the first 5 characters. I could be wrong though.

Code:

```
<cfif #queryName.TenDigitNumber# contains 'C'>
<td width="100" class=bodytext valign="top" >-#Plan.Code#-</td>
<cfelse>
<td width="100" class=bodytext valign="top" >#Plan.Code#</td>
</cfif>
```

This obviously encloses all 10 character strings that have C in them with dashes including something like 14CSI14550, which would be incorrect.  Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: +1 for a well phrased question. (Nothing to do with your question, but you can get rid of the `#` signs in the cfif. They are not necessary).

Comment: I've read that somewhere.  Is there a particular reason for this?  I'm assuming it's because since the queryName.TenDigitNumber is in cf tags.  This should mean it doesn't need the # signs because cf knows that it's a cf variable?  And then we use the # signs when it's not in a cf tag so HTML knows it's a variable?  Clarification would be great, thanks!

Comment: This might clear things up.  https://www.adobe.com/support/coldfusion/getting_started/using_poundsigns_quotat/using_poundsigns_quotat02.html

Comment: Well, according to CF legend, [excess `#` signs cause extra processing](http://www.adobe.com/support/coldfusion/getting_started/using_poundsigns_quotat/using_poundsigns_quotat02.html). I cannot say I ever noticed much of a difference. The primary reason is simply that it is extra code that is not needed and reduces readability.  In most cases CF automatically detects and evalutes variables within a cfset, cfif, etc.. Unless you enclose the variable/function in quotes.

Comment: Quotes signify a string. So CF will assume it is just text and ignore it unless you wrap the variable in `#` signs, forcing the CF engine to evaluate it. *so HTML knows it's a variable* Not quite. It is to let the *CF server* know the contents are a variable/function that must be evaluated. The CF server then generates HTML and sends it back to the browser. So HTML does not enter into it at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<cfif mid(queryname.tendigitnumber, 6, 1) eq 'C'> .. do stuff .. </cfif>
```